# two (2) django applications on same vps server

Tags: django, linux, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I have two django applications deployed on the same server. I wanted to know if the two applications can coexist together without causing problems when the server handles requests with nginx and gunicorn .

Answer (score 0):

You can serve the two Djangos on two separate ports if that's what you're wondering. Serve Nginx on an open port (like port 80) and upstream each request that hits port 80 based on the domain / rules. Upstream them to the proper port.